# I am not getting exactly gray image on converting video to grayscale?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

This is my code. The output is not exactly gray. Can someone tell me what is the problem in the code ?

```
 obj = VideoReader('shaky_cars.avi');
height = obj.Height;
width = obj.Width;

factor = 200/height;
num=10;
intendedFrame = 20;
video = read(obj , [intendedFrame , intendedFrame+num]);

for i = 1:1+num
    grayVideo(:,:,i) = double(imresize((rgb2gray(video(:,:,:,i))) , factor));
end

[height , width] = size(grayVideo(:,:,1));
figure(1);imagesc(grayVideo(:,:,1));
```

And this is the output[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few questions: Have you printed out the images before and after to see what's happening at each step?

Why are you converting the frames to type double?

Suggestion: Try converting the image to uint8 by doing `uint8(grayVideo(:,:,i))` and use a gray colormap `colormap(gray(256))`.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Great. Please accept my answer on the left side by clicking the green arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using imagesc, you can use

```
 imshow(uint8(grayVideo(:,:,1)))
```

to display your grayscale images.